# Enchanced For Loop for a String

Tags: java, for-loop

Hi i wanted to inquire about Enchanced for loops and Strings.

So i know that for ints the for loop is as so :

```
public static void main(String args[]){
int[] squares = {0,1,3,4,5}
for(int i = 0; i < squares.length; i++)
```

and you can make it an enhanced loop as follows

```
for (int i : squares)
```

but i wanted to know how to do both the regular for loop and enchanced for loop for a string?

Comment: What exactly are you trying to iterate? The characters of a `String`, or multiple `String`s in an array? Also, in Java 8+, you can use a `Stream`.

Answer (score 4):

Enhanced for loop only work for the types iterable or if the object of type is an array.

You cannot do it as String is not a Iterable type.

What you can do is, get the char array from string and iterate on it as

```
for (char c : str.toCharArray()) {


}
```

if it is an string array, you can simply change your data type to strings.

Comment: so would what you posted be changing the string to a character array?

Comment: It wont change the string, just for looping purposes you are doing it.

Answer (score 0):

YES, In regards to the language of **Java**, absolutely it can be done.

- First declare and initialize the String array called for example "name".

  ```
  String[] names = {"Bob","Jane","Joe"};
  ```
- Then using an **Enchanced Loop**:

  ```
  for(String i: names)
      System.out.println(i);
  ```
- Then using a **Regular for loop**

  ```
  for(int i=0; i<names.length; i++)
      System.out.println(names[i]);
  ```
- The result produced will be exactly the same for each loop:

  ```
  Bob
  Jane
  Joe
  ```

***Here is the complete code, as per above. Try it, it will work:***

```
    public static void main(String[] args) {

        String[] names = {"Bob","Jane","Joe"};

        for(String i: names)
            System.out.println(i); 

        for(int i=0; i<names.length; i++)
            System.out.println(names[i]);      
    }
```

Answer (score -1):

In the very same way:

```
String[] names = {"John","Jack","Bob","Tracey","Cindy"};
for(int i = 0; i < names.length; i++) {
    System.out.println(names[i]);
}
```

So called enhanced:

```
String[] names = {"John","Jack","Bob","Tracey","Cindy"};    
for (String i : names) {
    System.out.println(i);
}
```

Comment: Thank you so much!